# TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, if-statement, floating-point, typeerror

Why is the object being interpreted as a int and not a float.

```
main2 = True

while main2:
     try:
        amount = float(input('annual gross income: '))
        namount = float(amount)
        expenses = float(input('annual expenses: '))
        nnexpenses = float(expenses)



        if(9226 <= namount <= 37450):
                print('Your tax rate is  $922.50 + 15%')
                print(float(round(namount - namount*0.15 - 922.50 - nnexpenses)))
        if(namount <= 9225):
                print('Your tax rate is 10%')
                print(float(round(namount - namount*0.10 - nnexpenses,2)))
        if(37451 <= namount <= 90750 ):
                print('Your tax rate is  $5, 156.25 + 25%')
                print(float(round(amount - namount*0.25 - 5,156.25 - nnexpenses)))
        if(90751 <= namount <= 189300):
                 print('Your tax rate is  $18,481.25 + 28%')
                 print(float(round(amount - namount*0.28 - 18,481.25 - nnexpenses))) 
        if(189301 <= namount <= 411500):
                print('Your tax rate is  $46,075.25 + 33%')
                print(float(round(namount - namount*0.33 - 46,075.25 - nnexpenses)))
        if(411501 <= namount <= 413200):
                 print('Your tax rate is  $119,401.25 + 35%')
                 print(float(round(namount - namount*0.35 - 119,401.25 - nnexpenses)))
        if(413201 <= namount):
                 print('Your tax rate is  $119,996.25 + 39.6%')
                 print(float(round(namount - namount*0.396 - 119,996.25 - nnexpenses)))

        #print('Annual Net Income: ', round(result,2))
     except(ValueError,NameError):
         #if(ValueError):
         print('Please enter a number and postive balance.')
         #else:
             #print('Get out of debt')
```

Comment: Where are you getting that error?

Comment: if `46,075.25` means 46075.25 then you have a serious problem understanding the language. Very few languages support number separator, like `'` in C++14 (`46'075.25`) and `_` (`46_075.25`) in Verilog and Ada

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the commas from your numbers. The commas are being interpreted as argument separators, meaning `round` is being called with two arguments instead of one.

```
print(float(round(namount - namount*0.35 - 119,401.25 - nnexpenses)))
```

should be

```
print(float(round(namount - namount*0.35 - 119401.25 - nnexpenses)))
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are passing a floating point number as the second argument for [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round) . A very simple testcase to reproduce the issue -

```
>>> round(1.5,1.5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

From [documentation -](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round)

> **round(number[, ndigits])**
>
> Return the floating point value number rounded to ndigits digits after the decimal point. If ndigits is omitted, it defaults to zero.

The ndigits needs to be an integer, it signifies the number of digits after the decimal point.

But you are doing -

```
print(float(round(amount - namount*0.25 - 5,156.25 - nnexpenses)))
```

I am guessing you are trying to represent numbers with comma, but that is not how Python accepts it, if `5,156.25` is meant to be the number `5156.25` , then you need to remove the comma.

Comment: is there a way I can keep the decimal in or should I make it a int

Comment: Is `5,156.25` meant to be the number `5156.25` ?

Comment: If so, remove the comma for all the `round()` function calls.

Comment: Well answered . type casting like int() , or float() can also be used . as per requirement

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are using a comma in your values, for example here: `5,156.25` - for Python, this isn't "five thousand and one hundred and fifty six decimal two five".

Since you have added it to your call to `round`, the part after the comma gets added as second argument.

Your call is then:

```
round(5, 156.25)
```

Which will raise an error.

Remove the commas from your values, and you should get the results you expect.