# TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an index in Multi GPU's

Tags: python, tensorflow, typeerror

I am unable to understand why the my jupyter notebook is showing `TypeError` for float, each time I execute it.

```
A = np.random.rand(1e4, 1e4).astype('float32')
B = np.random.rand(1e4, 1e4).astype('float32')


c1 = []
c2 = []


def matpow(M, n):
    if n < 1:  #Abstract cases where n < 1
        return M
    else:
        return tf.matmul(M, matpow(M, n-1))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last) 
<ipython-input-5-61ea4b300d55> in <module>()
      1 # Example: compute A^n + B^n on 2 GPUs
      2 #Create random Large matrix
----> 3 A = np.random.rand(1e4, 1e4).astype('float32')
      4 B = np.random.rand(1e4, 1e4).astype('float32')
      5 
mtrand.pyx in mtrand.RandomState.rand()
mtrand.pyx in mtrand.RandomState.random_sample()
mtrand.pyx in mtrand.cont0_array()
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an index
```

Comment: Please format your question properly

Comment: This is a duplicate once you realize the OP meant integer and not index. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32687012/typeerror-float-object-cannot-be-interpreted-as-an-integer

Comment: You misstated your problem. Shouldn’t it say ‘float’ object cannot be interpreted as an integer? Not index. Same in title.

Answer (score 1):

Your TypeError is pretty clear. A float cannot be interpreted as an integer. Also, 1e4 is a float even if you don't try to cast it as a float, i.e. `>>>1v4` in python will output `10000.0` which is a float. You need to cast 1e4 as an integer for your code to work.

```
A = np.random.rand(int(1e4), int(1e4))
B = np.random.rand(int(1e4), int(1e4))
```

This will work, but why not just type 10000 for each instance of 1e4 rather than write more code to cast it as integer type?

Comment: `np.random.rand` always returns numbers in [0, 1). They specifying the shape to be (10000, 10000).

Comment: @xdurch0 you are right. I changed my post to reflect.